# Maximum dimensions of canvas in JavaFX

Tags: canvas, javafx-2, javafx

Does anyone know the maximum dimensions of a canvas in JavaFX? From some tests it seams to be 8192 (the same of IE) and, by my side, this is strange.
Maybe, is it modifiable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely it depends upon the maximum texture size for your video card as I believe, using the most common hardware accelerated rendering pipeline, the canvas will ultimately be represented as a texture. (I don't know this exactly, but I think it is a pretty good guess).

You can cross-post to [openjfx-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) to get a developer to confirm.

Comment: Based on your response, I did a little research on google. It seams to be right what you say: see this two links  [http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm)  [http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/66300-Texture-Size-Limit](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/66300-Texture-Size-Limit)  Thank you.